# How to determe if exception is compile time checked or runtime checked?

Tags: java, exception

I was looking at the `RuntTimeException` class and its not checked in compile time. How come  a class is not `checked` in compile time and `checked` at runtime?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

```
               | Throwable |
               +-----------+
                /         \
               /           \
      +-------+          +-----------+
      | Error |          | Exception |
      +-------+          +-----------+
       /  |  \           / |        \
     \________/        \______/      \
      unchecked                   checked
                +------------------+
                | RuntimeException |
                +------------------+
                  /   |    |      \
                \_________________/

                   unchecked
```

1. `RuntimeException` class extends `Exception` class and still is unchecked? How?.
2. How does the compiler decides whether this class should be checked in `runtime` or `compile` time?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RuntimeException class extends Exception class and still is unchecked? How?.

It's a design choice. The designers of the Java language decided that RuntimeException and Error, and classes that extends them are by definition unchecked exceptions. So it's just a rule of the language.

> How does the compiler decides whether this class should be checked in runtime or compile time?.

The compiler checks the type of the exception being thrown. If it is a RuntimeException or Error the exception is unchecked.

Comment: How does Java compiler decides is it based on the name or some class definition which makes the RuntimeException unchecked. Can i make a class similar to RuntimeException without extending the RunttimeException.

Comment: @Shane Yes, the code in a java compiler have to recognize the name RuntimeException in some manner as being special. No, you can't make such a thing yourself (at least not without changing code in the Java compiler first)

Comment: @Shane No it is not. An unchecked exception is a RuntimeException or an Error.

Answer (score 1):

A class is not checked, you are talking about exceptions here. An exception is whether compile-time checked or unchecked. A checked exception must be caught or declared in the signature of the method where it may be thrown. An unchecked exception does not require any particular treatment.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are as follows:

1. All exception classes that extend `RuntimeException` (including `RuntimeException` itself) are **unchecked** exceptions.
2. All other classes that extend `Exception` are **checked** exceptions - excluding `RuntimeException` and everything below that.
3. `Error` and everything below that is also unchecked.

"Checked" means that the Java compiler will check if your code either handles the exception by catching it, or if the method in which the exception might occur has a `throws` clause to indicate that this method might throw this type of exception.

See [The Catch or Specify Requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials which explains this in detail.

The answer to both your questions is: It works like that because it is specified like that in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: RuntimeException class extends Exception class and still is unchecked? How?

Comment: What do you mean "how"? It just works according to the rules. There is no reason this shouldn't work because `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`.

Comment: The rules of the language are Error and RuntimeException and their subclasses are unchecked exceptions. All other exceptions are Checked.

Comment: Yep, the fact that `RuntimeException` extends `Exception` is exactly why you should never catch `Exception` "in its entirety" -- unless you have dealt with `RuntimeException` before